# Google support Map crashing

Tags: android, android-layout, gmsmapview, supportmapfragment

Google SupportMapFragment is crashing when executing this

```
( (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
              R.id.map)).getMapAsync(googleMap -> presenter.onMapReady(googleMap, getContext()));
```

with the nullpointer and the stacktrace is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16
> (150400-0):2)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16
> (150400-0):2)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16
> (150400-0):18)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16
> (150400-0):14)
> at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16
> (150400-0):44)

xml for the supportfragment is

```
<fragment
                        android:id="@+id/map"
                        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google Map [issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/748). Clearing the app cache helps me.